# Meteor compile errors

Tags: meteor

I checked out 86a52e6 on the master branch from the Meteor repo. Ran ./scripts/generate-dev-bundle.sh per the Slow Start (for developers) instructions. This goes off to work for awhile, generating a ton of output but ending with [errors](http://hastebin.com/sahamaxaco.md). All of them seem to be unused private fields in third-party libraries.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Any guidance would be most welcome! I've been getting to know my way around Meteor via the pre-compiled binaries, but this was my first attempt to build from scratch.

Running OSX 10.8.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you try compile Node.js try to watch http://nodejs.org/download/ for binary

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile your own dev_bundle. On first time you run `meteor` from the checkout, it will download compiled binaries (mongod, mongo, node and npm) for your system architecture.

Don't bother yourself compiling, just use ready binaries.